# Why can't I use class or ids within bootstrap poppver

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a popover menu using bootstrap popover. I can put html within the popover if i do data-html="true". However, what i start adding class names or ids on divs, it breaks the popover.

```
<a href="#" id="example" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true"     title data-original-title="Test title"data-content="
 <div ="test">
  test content
  <ul>
    <li>d</li>
  </ul>
 </div>">
```

renders this outside of the popover:

```
test content
d
```

Any idea whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes in your ids or names as double quotes break your data-content.

```
<a href="#" id="example" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true"     title data-original-title="Test title"data-content="
 <div ='test'>
  test content
  <ul>
    <li>d</li>
  </ul>
 </div>" > </a>
```